# Workflow On List Item getting error

Tags: central-administration, workflow-manager, workflow2013

Getting error after installing the security updates in sharepoint2013 , checked services and restarted IIS also and restarted workflowmgmt but nothing solved issue.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you perhaps ran psconfig without the correct switches. Either use the Config Wizard, or you can also run `Install-SPApplicationContent`.

Comment: in my company the network guys installed security patch , from then this issue started coming , i checked all workflowmgmt sevice and restarted also, even restarted all services which are using with SP_workflow account

Comment: You need to run the Config Wizard. You may need to educate your network guys. Simply installing any SharePoint update is not sufficient to patch a SharePoint farm. See [Install a software update (SharePoint 2013)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806338.aspx).

Comment: even i am unable to publish workflow and unable to run the workflow on the list item , when you submit the item it's getting saved in list but it is not running the workflow on the list

Comment: I'll be repeating the same thing, I'm afraid. You MUST run the Config Wizard at this point on all members of the farm. If you still have this issue after running the Config Wizard, then we can expand on this.